# How to get the input string from a text area in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I already have an existing code which I am trying to understand and to tweak it a little bit. I have a text area, as and when a person types in the text, the list shows all the words starting with that character. The problem that I am facing is, what I guess is probably it is not able to fetch or get the typed text or character, hence as soon as I input something and even though there is an item in the list starting with that character, it says no matching item in the list. I won't be able to share the whole code as it is too long and has a lot of files associated, hence sharing only a snippet of it.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.loadWithQuery = this.loadWithQuery.bind(this);
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);
    }

render(){
<SafeAreaView style={{flex : 1, backgroundColor : "white"}}>
            <Search 
                renderItem={this.renderItem}
                placeholder={"Enter OS Name1"}
                refreshing={loading}
                loadWithQuery={this.loadWithQuery}
                data={osNames}
                title={"Select OS Name"}
                error={error}
            />
            </SafeAreaView>
}

renderItem = ({item}) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onPress(item)}>
                <View style={styles.container}> 
                    <Text style={styles.name} value={item.os_name} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    };

loadWithQuery(searchedString){
        const {
            customerId,
            token
        } = this.props;
        console.log("query", query)
        this.props.getOsNames(token, customerId, searchedString);
    }
```

Comment: This sounds like an autocomplete component?

Comment: Yeah sort of but the data for the list is coming from database